# Saltstack: Using specific tag as GitFS remote

Tags: salt-stack

It is my understanding from [the Salt GitFS docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html#gitfs-per-remote-config), that I can set `gitfs_base` to point at a tag in my remote. It doesn't work - Salt doesn't find any of the states defined in my remote. Please can someone explain what I'm missing?

My `/etc/salt/minion`:

```
file_client: local

fileserver_backend:
  - git

gitfs_base: v0.2.0

gitfs_remotes:
  - git://github.com/mafrosis/salt-formulae
```

Comment: Since Git remote now has per remote base tag - try that as suggested here at https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html#gitfs-per-remote-config and also since you have dots in your tag - try adding quotes around it. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I have tried using the per-remote setting also - they did not work. Escaping dots should not be necessary in YAML.

Comment: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/27432

Comment: Just noticed you have set this in minion setting file - shouldn't these be in master setting file?

Comment: noted - looks like a bug